# PHP Gmail API: can send email but how to add recipient email

Tags: php, gmail-api

I have a working gmail api php code grabbed from `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/`

I am able to send email with the following code but without a recipient. In gmail sent items I can also see the message sent!

```
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($_POST["message"]), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$x = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

How do I add a recipient email address? In few posts I read that `To` should be added to the header.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?  I'm getting the "Recipient address required" error, but I've set the "To" value.

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add To, Cc, or Bcc headers to the email message to send the email to people.  In your case, the $_POST["message"] string or even better yet some email message object using a standard php email library.

See:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: I am confused. Where do I add the To, CC or BCC in the code I have mentioned. Could you add a code snippet?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I dropped the plan and moved to zapier. You can try this https://zapier.com/apps/gmail/integrations

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a raw email to \Google_Service_Gmail_Message() class.
This raw message should be a mime message base64 encoded. Pretty much everything you did.

**BUT**: you need not to pass the email body (like the content of the email address), but literally the whole email - with headers. So not `$_POST["message"]` should be passed, but a prepared email that has all the required headers, including TO, FROM etc. Here is an example:

```
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: YOUR CUSTOM SUBJECT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=5ae50a40c56153a0ca99d08aaf8f99d53f63981962d4f199b2339614636b

--5ae50a40c56153a0ca99d08aaf8f99d53f63981962d4f199b2339614636b
YOUR CUSTOM EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE. Might be a mix of html and plain text.
--5ae50a40c56153a0ca99d08aaf8f99d53f63981962d4f199b2339614636b--
```

It's much better to use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/phpmailer/phpmailer) class to prepare the whole MIME version of the email for you, where you just pass to its public methods required data, subject, FROM, TO, body etc - and then request a MIME with a single method like this `$phpmailer->getSentMIMEMessage()`.